# Evaluate all records or evaluate new records only?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have activated a journey with a Data Extension as an entry source. This Data Extension is configured with an overwrite query on a daily basis.
Btw, I have configured the journey with "evaluate new records only" as contact evaluation.

Can an overwrite and an "evaluate new records only" parameter work together please?

Answer (score 2):

They don't work together or rather it makes no sense. Because when you overwrite all records, all records will be "new" records, therefore you can just chose evaluate all.